# Linux: system protection against C++ and FORTRAN programs which like to crash often

Tags: c++, linux, crash, fortran, freeze

I have a program which runs for a long time, about 3 weeks. It's actually a simulation application.

After that time usually the memory gets full, the system becomes unresposive and I have to restart the whole computer. I really don't want to do that and since we are talking about Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS I think there is a way to avoid that. Swap is turned off, because getting stuff of the program to swap would slow it down too much.

The programm is partly written in C++ (about 10%) and FORTRAN (about 90%), and is compiled and linked using the GNU Compiler Suite (g++ and gfortran).

Getting to my question:

Is there a good way to protect the system against those programs which mess it up other than a virtual machine?

P.S.: I know the program has bugs but I cannot fix them right now, so I want to protect the system against hang ups. Also I cannot use a debugger, because it would run for too long.

Edit:

After some comments, I want to clarify some things. The code is way too complex. I don't have the time to fix the bugs and there are versions in which I don't even get the source code. I have to run it, because we are forced to do so. You do not have always the choice.

Not running a program like this is not an option because it still produces some results. So restarting the system is a workaround but I would like to do better. I consider ulimit an option, Didn't think about that one. It might help.

Comment: So, you don´t want to fix the bugs, but instead you want to use a VM to fill the memory even more and slow everything down? Nonsense. Fix the bugs.

Comment: "*Is there a good way to protect the system against those programs*" Do not run them? To be honest, what kind of tool do you expect? The only one (possibly) able to remove the code leaking memory, is the coder, isn't s/he?

Comment: ...and if the OS swap mechanism isn´t good enough for you, build something in your program that data *you know* that it isn´t needed is written to files.

Comment: What you *could* do is let the program monitor its memory consumption, and when a certain threshold is met, dump all relevant data to disk, let the program exec a new instance of itself loading the dumped data and then end itself.

Comment: And extension to the suggestion from @alk is to use `ulimit` to set the maximum amount of memory the application is allowed to use, and let the process die from "out of memory" (a relatively long way) before it gets to the point where Linux is swapping so badly that you can't use the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limiting this crappy application memory is the easiest part. You can for example use Docker (https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/09/11/resource-management-in-docker/#_memory), or cgroup, which are kind of virtual machine but with much less overhead. `ulimit` may also be an option, as mentioned in the comments.

The real problem here is to realize that if your simulation program gets killed when it runs out of memory, can you actually use the generated results? Is this program doing some checkpointing to recover from a crash?

Also badly written programs with memory leaks also frequently have more serious problems like overflows, which can turn the results totally useless if you do real science.

You may try to use valgrind to debug memory issues. Fortran also has nice compilation directives for array bounds checking, you should activate those settings if you can.

Comment: Hey, that helped me a lot. Thank you very much! I have to learn more about the Docker stuff.